# PLACEHOLDER - System to facilitate the indexing and archiving of Web3 Discord questions

Tags: script, placeholder

LUNA_Discord is the Discord module of the LUNA system which facilitates the integration of Cyfrin's Discord Bot with various AI models and systems.

Access to the Stack Exchange API will be used to consolidate high quality questions posed in Discord into an avenue through which they may be indexed by Search Engines and future AI foundation models.